# Como leer json con php

Tags: php, json

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
{
  "marca": {
    "0": "Eneba",
    "4": "Epic Games",
    "11": "Steam",
    "16": "Roblox",
    "19": "Xbox",
    "69": "Gocash game"
  }
}
```

Necesito leerlo con PHP pero el problema es que los números son dinámicos, no siempre son los mismos (0,4,11,16,etc.) que solución proponen?

Gracias

Comment: Que has intentado? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es relativamente facil, lo primero es esa cadena JSON convertirla a un array con la funcion [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) y despues leer el array, por ejemplo:

Asi conviertes a array

```
$cadena_json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$arreglo = json_decode($cadena_json );
```

y despues lees el array

```
foreach($arreglo as $valor=>$dato)
    {
    echo "El valor de: " . $valor. " es = " . $dato;
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

ya en tu caso te generaria un arreglo un poco mas complejo, pero las bases son las mismas

Comment: Si te fijaste en el problema que plantea el OP verdad?

Comment: Gracias! funciono correctamente!